# Fabric Capacity metrics data REST API or alternate ways to pull it

Tags: rest, powerbi, microsoft-fabric

I have quite a few activities going on on Power BI.
I have admin access and want to be able to pull in information like CPU usage, usage spike with respect to time etc.
I came across an inbuilt app that has an inbuilt dataset that creates such graphics. It was Fabric Capacity Usage metrics.
Now I want pull this data supporting these visuals and periodically save it in an object storage solution.
Is there a REST API available to pull in this data from the Fabric Usage Capacity Metrics app?
If such an API is not available, what are some ways by which I can pull this data in python?